# Adding multiple PDFs into HTML

Tags: html, pdf

```
            <section class="features section-padding" id="features">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="feature-list">
                    <h3>San Diego</h3>
                    <p>Departure</p>
                      <body>
                        <iframe src="http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/SAN/APD/AIRPORT+DIAGRAM/pdf" width="600" height="700">
                        <iframe src="https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KSAN/DP/all/pdf" width="600" height="700">
                      </body>
                    <p>Approach</p>
                      <body>
                        <iframe src="https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KSAN/STAR/all/pdf" width="600" height="700">
                        <iframe src="https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KSAN/IAP/all/pdf" width="750" height="800">
                      </body>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
       </section>
```

That is what I have at the moment, but it only shows one pdf, the top one. How can I get it to show all the pdfs?

Thanks

Comment: you can use body once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to close your iframe tags.

The iframe tag is not self closing and should be explicitly closed like the following:

```
<iframe src="https://www.weather.com" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
```

(Notice the `</iframe>` closing tag)

This one worked for me (your original HTML re-worked):

```
<section class="features section-padding" id="features">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="feature-list">
                <h3>San Diego</h3>
                <p>Departure</p>
                  <div>
                  <iframe src="https://www.weather.com" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
                    <iframe src="https://www.weather.com" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
                  </div>
                <p>Approach</p>
                  <div>
                    <iframe src="https://www.weather.com" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
                    <iframe src="https://www.weather.com" width="750" height="800"></iframe>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/c55zztbn

If you are still not getting your iframe's src URL's shown, the url you are using might be using a "X-Frame-Options" response header which will prevent the iframe from loading it.

Hope that it helps a bit!